# Mixed derivative PDE, is my solution correct?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Say I had a PDE:

$$\frac{\partial ^2 u }{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =y$$

And I want to solve it. I first integrated to get:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +\frac{1}{x}u  = \frac{y^2}{2}$$

But I am unable to resolve this further

Comment: Dont forget the constant of integration $h(x)$.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +\frac{1}{x}u  = \frac{y^2}{2}+h(x)$$$$(ux)'  = \frac{xy^2}{2}+g(x)$$Then integrate with respect to the variable $x$ and dont forget the constant of integration $f(y)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial ^2 u }{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =y$$
Substitue $v=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$:
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} +\frac{v}{x}  = y$$
It's like an ode:
$$xv' +v  = xy$$
$$(vx)'=xy$$
Integrate with respect to the variable $x$:
$$vx=y\dfrac {x^2}{2}+f(y)$$

Now write  $v=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$
$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\dfrac {yx^2}{2}+f(y)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\dfrac {xy}{2}+\dfrac {f(y)}{x}$$

And solve by integration with respect to the variable $y$.
$$\boxed {u(x,y)=\dfrac {xy^2}{4}+\dfrac {g(y)}{x}+h(x)}$$

Comment: $u = xy$? I'm not sure how to get past that point

Comment: Integrate like I did in my answer with respect to the variable $x$ @Roberto_1986